# Which files should be skipped when deploy to GAE flexible environment?

Tags: google-app-engine

For example, I have a `react.js` project.

Here is my `app.flex.yaml`:

```
service: SPA-websocket-front-end
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
skip_files:
  - src
  - public
  - tsconfig.json
  - .gitignore
  - node_modules
```

After reading this doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml, 
It's a very little description about `skip_files` config.

My thinking is just upload `build` directory, `package.json`, `yarn.lock` and `app.flex.yaml` files to `cloud build` for `GAE`.

Because `cloud build` use `docker` to build an image, so the config of `skip_files` should be same with `.dockerignore` in order to reduce the size of `docker` uploaded context.

I am not sure whether or not the config of `skip_files` is pass to `cloud build`.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

`skip_files` is not recommended for Cloud Build. Use [.gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) instead.

While `skip_files` works only in the app.yaml, .gcloudignore works in a more global way as it can be used with:

```
gcloud beta app deploy
gcloud beta functions deploy
gcloud builds submit
gcloud container builds submit
gcloud beta debug source upload
```